# Why can't we turn off firewall And file sharing?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, security, firewall, file-sharing

I was under the impression that turning off file sharing "makes it more secure". Especially when I like to have my firewall switched off, turning off file sharing becomes more important to me.

[image]

But I couldn't find a way to turn off fire sharing without having the firewall automatically turned on. Does anyone know why do we have to enable firewall if file sharing is turned off?

More importantly, how do I keep both features switched off?

Comment: Since file sharing is explicit, if you share no files, it is off for all practical purposes.

Comment: Your earlier question http://superuser.com/questions/346472/file-sharing-vs-file-and-printer-sharing-for-microsoft-networks contains the answer to this one - use the Local Area Connection Properties dialog to disable or uninstall the file sharing component without using the firewall.

Comment: Oh, and for the record - if you're determined to run without a firewall, then disabling the file and printer sharing component would definitely be a sensible precaution.

Comment: You should also check for any other components that might be listening on the network.  Use netstat -a and look for ports in the "LISTENING" state.

Comment: @HarryJohnston ic, just to confirm, so if my firewall is turned off, and I have disabled "file and printer sharing for microsoft networks", even if I **do** have this "file sharing" turned on (as in the picture above), it is basically misleading because "file sharing" is **not** turned on. right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @surfasb, for the record, that's not true - Windows automatically shares the entire drive (or drives as the case may be) and also the C:\Windows folder and (even worse) the IPC$ share which allows a remote admin to run code.  All of these are restricted to administrators, but if you don't have a strong administrator password they may present a risk.  (I have the impression this risk is mitigated on modern Windows if UAC is turned on, but I'm unclear on the details and don't know how solid the mitigation is.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but AFAIK turning off file sharing just configures the firewall to block the applicable ports, which it can't do of course if the firewall isn't running.

The real question should be, why are you trying to 'make your machine more secure', but at the same time disabling the firewall it comes with?

- If you're running in a trusted LAN (e.g. a home network), you're
  probably ok
- If you're using another firewall product, you have to
  configure that separately to block file sharing

Otherwise, I would say you're better off learning how to configure the firewall to do what you want.  Most of this can be done simply by making sure the [profile is set correctly](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851569.aspx).

Comment: To put it another way: it's not that you're turning off a filesharing service. It's that you're using the firewall service to block remote access to essential part of windows.

Comment: I'm trying to make the computer as secure as possible without having to run programs like *live* anti-virus and firewall

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn are you saying that even if "filesharing" is turned off, files can still be shared?

Comment: AFAIK, Windows exposes filesharing as part of the Workstation service, which performs other networking-related services as part of its job. The firewall can be configured to block connections to that service from your local network (aka 'turning off file sharing;).  You could stop that service, but you'd lose other functionality; a firewall really is the better way to fix this.  For more info on the default shares created by Windows, see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share#Preventing_access)